# How a Ruby class to initialize all included modules?

Tags: ruby

See the following sample code first:

```
module First
  def initialize
    puts "Second init"
  end

  def first
    puts "first"
  end
end

module Second
  def initialize
    puts "Second init"
  end

  def second
    puts "second"
  end
end

class MyClass
  include First
  include Second

  def initialize
    super()
  end
end

c = MyClass.new
c.first
c.second
```

Output of this program is:

```
Second init
first
second
```

From the output, we can see that `MyClass` has well included `First` and `Second` modules, because it has both `first()` and `second()` methods.

In `MyClass` constructor, I try to initialize both included modules with `super()`, but it seems only `Second`'s constructor is called.

How to initialize all included modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`include` inserts a module in between the present class and its ancestors. Since `First`, then `Second` was included, the ancestors of `MyClass` is

```
[MyClass, Second, First, ...]
```

The keyword `super` looks for the first method available in the ancestor class besides its own class. And it finds `Second#initialize`.

If you want to accumulate the `initialize` methods of the ancestor modules, then do this:

```
module First
  def initialize
    puts "Second init"
  end
end

module Second
  include First
  def initialize
    super
    puts "Second init"
  end
end

class MyClass
  include Second
  def initialize
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: Then how to initialize First module?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it turns out a new problem. If MyClass inherit from MyBaseClass, and MyBaseClass constructor requires two parameters, and First is a third party module, then looks like the initialize chain would have trouble, because it needs First to call super to init MyBaseClass, but First doesn't know MyBaseClass constructor requires two parameter. How to solve this problem?

Comment: @Evan Li Not sure I understand.  As long as First has 'super' in initialize(), it will pass on all the arguments it receives.  Note super() is not the same; super() will pass no arguments.

Answer (score 2):

These module should call `super` in there own `initialize`:

```
module First
  def initialize
    puts "First init"
    super
  end

  def first
    puts "first"
  end
end

module Second
  def initialize
    puts "Second init"
    super
  end

  def second
    puts "second"
  end
end

class MyClass
  include First
  include Second

  def initialize
    super
  end
end

c = MyClass.new
c.first
c.second
```

output:

> Second init
>   First init
>   first
>   second

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it turns out a new problem. If MyClass inherit from MyBaseClass, and MyBaseClass constructor requires two parameters, and First is a third party module, then looks like the initialize chain would have trouble, because it needs First to call super to init MyBaseClass, but First doesn't know MyBaseClass constructor requires two parameter. How to solve this problem?